# JavaScript convert YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest(w, q, m, S) Callback to Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I am faced with some very old JavaScript code that uses `YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest()` to speak with a REST API. I would like to wait for the response of the `asyncRequest` and then work with the `response-data`. The current code structure does not suffice, because I want to "stay" in the current JS method to keep the state.

My thought was to convert the callback to a promise, i.e. "promisify" the method call. However the examples I could find so far did not bring me to a working solution yet.

If there is a better more up to date solution to the `YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest()`, I might also welcome that.

This is how the code currently looks like:

```
async function showEditBookingDialogue(bookingForm, courtOnline) {
    //ToDo: Consolidate all the prompts into one window.


    let bookingAttributes = bookingForm.getAttribute('data').split('_');
    let bookingId = bookingAttributes[0];

    //I would like to wait for the response here:
    YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', 'com/cms/BookingRequestHandler.php?action=checkpermissions&bid=' + bid, callback);

    ...
}

...


var callback = {
    customevents: {
        onStart: handleEvent.start,
        onComplete: handleEvent.complete,
        onSuccess: handleEvent.success,
        onFailure: handleEvent.failure,
        onUpload: handleEvent.upload,
        onAbort: handleEvent.abort
    },
    scope: handleEvent,
    argument: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
};

var handleEvent = {
    start: function (eventType, args) {
    },
    complete: function (eventType, args) {
    },
    success: function (eventType, args) {
        handleResponse(eventType, args);
    },
    failure: function (eventType, args) {
        handleResponse(eventType, args);
    },
    upload: function (eventType, args) {
        handleResponse(eventType, args);
    },
    abort: function (eventType, args) {
    }
};
```

My current attempts look something like that, however nothing is logged in the console:

```
    const promise = (...args) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', 'com/cms/BookingRequestHandler.php?action=checkpermissions&bid=' + bid, (err, data) => {
                if (err) return reject(err)
                resolve(data)
            })
        })
    }

    await promise()
        .then(data => {
            console.log("works")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("error")
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at example code such as [this one](http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0_full/connection/), and even your original code, shows that the `callback` should be an object of handlers. Though [official docs](https://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.5.2/docs/YAHOO.util.Connect.html) also state that a `function` also is accepted, so it's kinda confusing.

Here is an example of how you could build it using the `callback` object.

```
const yahooConnectRequest = body =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const callback = {
      success: resolve,
      failure: reject,
    };
    
    YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', 'com/cms/BookingRequestHandler.php', callback, body);
  });
```

Although you *can* use `then` chaining with `async`, it doesn't make much sense, unless you have a case that needs it. The example below is how you could do it without `then`.

```
// in async context.

try {
  const body = 'action=checkpermissions&bid=1234';
  const response = await yahooConnectRequest(body);
  console.log(response);
} catch(error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

I'm curious to learn if this worked out.